# Find an example of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ these conditions:

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure. Find an example of Lebesgue measurable subsets $A_1, A_2, \dots$ of $[0,1]$ such that $m(A_n) > 0$ for each $n$, $m(A_n \Delta A_m) >0$ if $m \neq n$, and $m(A_n \cap A_m) = m(A_n)m(A_m)$ if $m\neq n$.

I've spent some time trying to come up with examples of sets that satisfy these conditions and here's what I've come up with so far:

These sets can't be properly nested since this would not satisfy the multiplicative property.

Each set must intersect every other set in order to satisfy the multiplicative property.

I've tried many variations of shifting shrinking closed intervals through the interval $[0,1]$.

Any nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Think of Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$ as a uniform distribution and try to find stocastically independent subsets with measure strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\theta_k}{2^k}$ be the representation of the real number $\theta \in [0,1]$ in the binary system. For $n=1,2,\cdots$, we set $A_n=\{ \theta: \theta \in [0,1]\& \theta _n=0\}$. The $(A_n)_{n \in N}$ is a required  sequence of subsets of $[0,1]$.

Comment: For $A_n$, constructed in my answer of Jun 10, we have $m(A_n)=1/2$ and $\mu(A_i \cap A_j)=1/4$ for different $i,j$. Hence we have $m(A_i\cap A_j)=1/4=1/2\times 1/2=m(A_i)\times m(A_j)$ for different $i,j$.

Comment: Notice that $(A_n+1/2^n)\cap A_n =\emptyset$ and $(A_n+1/2^n)\cup A_n =[0,1]$ for each $n \in N$. From invariance of the measure $m$ we have $m(A_n+1/2^n)=m(A_n)$ which implies that $m(A_n)=1/2$.

Comment: For different natural numbers $i,j$ we have that  $\{(A_i\cap A_j)+1/2^i,(A_i\cap A_j)+1/2^j,(A_i\cap A_j)+1/2^i+1/2^j,(A_i\cap A_j)\}$ is the family of pairwise disjoint sets whose union is $[0,1]$. Using again translation invariance  of $m$ we conclude that $m(A_i \cap A_j)=1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Michael's comment, here's what I've come up with:

Let $A_n = \cup_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \left[\frac{2k-1}{2^n}, \frac{2k}{2^n}\right] $. Since each of these are countable unions of closed intervals, they are certainly Lebesgue measurable, and we claim that this sequence satisfies the given conditions.

If we fix an $A_n$, then this set is comprised of $2^{n-1}$ disjoint unions each of which has length $2^n$. Thus, $m(A_n) = 2^{n-1}\cdot(1/2^n) = 1/2> 0$ for each $n$.

I'm not exactly sure how to $prove$ that these satisfy that the last two conditions are true, but they are certainly clear if you just draw some number lines and see the pattern.

Comment: You can prove that these satisfy the last two conditions as follows:  Notice that $\{(A_i\cap A_j), (A_i\cap A_j)-1/2^i, (A_i\cap A_j)-1/2^j, (A_i\cap A_j)-1/2^j-1/2^i\}$ is a partition of $[0,1]$. From translation invariance of $m$, each element of this family  has the equal Lebesgue measure. Hence $m(A_i\cap A_j) =1/4$. Now the proof of the independence of this family of subsets is obvious.

Comment: Our $A_n$ are different. At you $A_n=\{ \theta:\theta \in[0,1]\&\theta_k=1\}$. At me $A_n= \{ \theta:\theta \in[0,1]\&\theta_k=0\}$.